# How to use Animation when I use multithread (application.class)

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm not native English Speaker.
If you don't understand what I'm writing, please let me know.

This is question.

I want to control `startColorAnimation` in MainActivity.
However, I'm using Multithread.
It means I am using Application.class.
This Application class send data[id] to MainActivity(and startColorAnimation).

if I use Multithread, I have to use "handler".
But, I cannot understand how to write code.

Please tell me how to write handler (and others).

here is `startColorAnimation` in `MainActivity`.

```
public void startColorAnimation(int id){

    if (id == mode) return;
    if(COLOR_START.length <= id || COLOR_END.length <= id ) return;
    mode = id;
    int colorStart = COLOR_START[id];
    int colorEnd = COLOR_END[id];
    int setDuration = PATTERN[id];


    ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(image, "backgroundColor", colorStart, colorEnd);
    colorAnim.setDuration(1000);
    colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    colorAnim.setRepeatCount(1);
    colorAnim.start();

}
```

Comment: In order to your Application to access your MainActivity you have to pass it to your Application and store it as a weak reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your trying to do GUI stuff on a Thread which is going to fail, you can use something like this:

I am using a runOnUiThread which will then do the animation on the GUI thread and should solve your problem, simple replace "MainActivity" with the Activity name.

```
public void startColorAnimation (int id) {

    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread (new Runnable () {
        public void run () {
            if (id == mode) return;
            if (COLOR_START.length <= id || COLOR_END.length <= id) return;
            mode = id;
            int colorStart = COLOR_START[id];
            int colorEnd = COLOR_END[id];
            int setDuration = PATTERN[id];


            ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt (image, "backgroundColor", colorStart, colorEnd);
            colorAnim.setDuration (1000);
            colorAnim.setEvaluator (new ArgbEvaluator ());
            colorAnim.setRepeatCount (1);
            colorAnim.start ();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct :) Click the tick next to my answer, this helps people know that this already has an accepted answer :) Glad I could help!